# Protect an Azure API from external Access

Tags: azure

We have created mutiple API Apps for our application. However these API Apps are connected to the internet so we need to protect them. We have chosen for an API Key, but we would like to have the API disconnected from the Internet, such that only our own applications can access them. Is there a way to disconnect them from internet access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each API App is automatically connected to the Internet and this can not be disabled. If you want to have an isolated environment you will have to create an App Service Environment. This will create an environment for with mutiple zone that can contain mutiple App Service Providers. It also create a virtual network that protect the resources in the ASE. You can configure the virtual network using access rules to only allow a certain IP address or none at all.

For more information about Azure Service Environment see: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-app-service-environment-intro/